# The read from a TCP Server hangs when reading more than once

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I am testing some TCP code and it seems to work fine except for one problem. The read from the socket hangs in one of the methods when there is nothing more to read:

Here is the TCP code:

```
package com.comp424.service;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TCPService implements Runnable
{
    protected int             serverPort;
    protected InetAddress     bindAddress;

    protected ServerSocket    serverSocket  = null;
    protected boolean         isStopped     = false;
    protected Thread          runningThread = null;

    protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public TCPService(String host,int port)
    {
        serverPort = port;

        try
        {
            bindAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get bind address", e);
        }
    }

    private void start()
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort, 10, bindAddress);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port " + serverPort, e);
        }
    }

    public void run()
    {
        synchronized (this)
        {
            runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }

        start();

        while (!isStopped())
        {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (isStopped())
                {
                    System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
                    break;
                }
                throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
            }

            threadPool.execute(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();

        System.out.println("Server Stopped.");
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        isStopped = true;

        try
        {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error closing server", e);
        }
    }    

    private synchronized boolean isStopped()
    {
        return isStopped;
    }  
}

package com.comp424.service;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import com.comp424.impl.dao.DaoFactory;
import com.comp424.intf.dao.ICourseDao;
import com.comp424.intf.dao.IPersonDao;
import com.comp424.intf.dao.IRegisterCourseDao;
import com.comp424.model.Course;
import com.comp424.model.Person;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
    private static IRegisterCourseDao registrationDao;
    private static IPersonDao         personDao;
    private static ICourseDao         courseDao;

    protected Socket                  clientSocket = null;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket)
    {
        registrationDao = DaoFactory.getInstance().getCourseRegistrationDao();
        personDao = DaoFactory.getInstance().getPersonDao();
        courseDao = DaoFactory.getInstance().getCourseDao();
        clientSocket = socket;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            String command = null;

            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            command = buffer.readLine();

            while (command != null)
            {
                String separator = ":";

                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(command, separator);

                List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();

                while (tokenizer.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    tokens.add((String) tokenizer.nextElement());
                }

                int operation = Integer.parseInt(tokens.get(0));

                switch (operation)
                {
                    case 1:
                        try
                        {
                            Person person = personDao.findByID(Long.parseLong(tokens.get(1)));
                            Course course = courseDao.findByID(Long.parseLong(tokens.get(2)));

                            registrationDao.register(person, course);
                            output.write(("0\r\n").getBytes());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            output.write(("1\r\n").getBytes());
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        try
                        {
                            Person person = personDao.findByID(Long.parseLong(tokens.get(1)));
                            Course course = courseDao.findByID(Long.parseLong(tokens.get(2)));

                            registrationDao.register(person, course);
                            output.write(("0\r\n").getBytes());
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            output.write(("1\r\n").getBytes());
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        try
                        {
                            Person person = personDao.findByID(Long.parseLong(tokens.get(1)));

                            List<Course> courses = registrationDao.findByPerson(person);

                            for (Course c : courses)
                            {
                                output.write((c.getName() + "\r\n").getBytes());
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            output.write(("1\r\n").getBytes());
                        }
                        break;

                }
                command = buffer.readLine();
            }

            output.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // report exception somewhere.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code where it just hangs in findRegisteredCourses() after reading two strings returned instead of exiting the while loop:

```
    while (response != null)
    {
        result.add(response);
        System.out.println("findRegisteredCourses():Response = " + response);
        response = reader.readLine();

    }
```

Full code for findRegisteredCourses():

```
    @Override
    public List<String> findRegisteredCourses(String personID) throws Exception
    {
        try (Socket server = new Socket("localhost", 7000))
        {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream()));

            String operation = "3:" + personID + "\r\n";
            writer.writeBytes(operation);
            writer.flush();

            String response = reader.readLine();

            while (response != null)
            {
                result.add(response);
                System.out.println("findRegisteredCourses():Response = " + response);
                response = reader.readLine();

            }
            server.close();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what `server.stop()` should do , we don't know whether the "other code" might be relvant. We need more information.

Comment: Sorry, I will post the server code. The "other code" is just reading, writing some data and is not relevant.

Comment: Even if the server code has some issue, I wonder why System.out.println("Stopping Server"); is not executed?

Comment: That should be a problem in "other code".

Comment: OK I have found out why the print does not execute. The code hangs in one of the methods. I will modify the original problem and restate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're continuing to try to read from the server until it's closed the socket - whereas the server is waiting for another command from the client. Neither side is going to do anything, as they're waiting for the other.

Basically, you need to change your protocol, either to have some "here's the end of the response" indication (such as an empty line, if that's not a valid value in the response data), or to only have a single request/response per connection.

Your suggested "fix" of using the `ready()` method is very broken - it basically means you assume there's no more data as soon as there's a pause. Maybe the server is taking a while to find the next item. Maybe there's a delay on the network - or maybe it's finished. You can't tell, and basically you're violating the design of streaming protocols (such as TCP) by trying to infer information from the fact that there's no data available *right now*. Don't do that - fix your protocol.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your suggestions. I just fixed the issue by using the reader.ready() call to see if there was more to read. I will update my post.

Comment: @DocMartin: No, that's absolutely the *wrong* fix - it will break as soon as you have a flaky network connection, so that there's no more to read *right now* but there might be in the future. You have to treat TCP connections as streams of data, without inferring anything from timing of "there's nothing there right now, therefore there won't be anything in the future."

Comment: OK so I am really lost now. So the server sends me two strings and then goes into wait for another client. But how do I detect in the calling method that there is no more data coming after two strings and break out of the loop?

Comment: @DocMartin: You don't, that's my point. That's not how streaming protocols work. You can't wait for an absence of data. You can wait for the connection to be closed, or you can wait to see some special "end token" (maybe an empty line?) or you can wait until you've read a pre-specified amount of data.

Comment: The calling method could "know" that there are only two strings coming, and not expect any more. Or the server could send two strings and then an "end of transmission" message indicating it's done.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. That will definitely work. I'll just send a special token at the end. Much appreciated you saving me from the broken use of read().

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my original answer because it was wrong as per @Jon Skeet's comments. I now just send a special end of data token and it works fine.

Comment: We have all been there when `Jon Skeet` is involved.